# Web Accessibility - empty links

Tags: jquery, html, web-applications

As part of the accessibility assessment of our site, some empty links are being picked up as an issue

The links are calendar icons against date-pickers (the site is ASP.NET MVC/Razor using jQuery)

```
<a href='#' class="icon-calendar"></a>
```

What is the best solution to make these items accessibility compliant?

Should we add an `alt` attribute or add some hidden text within the link? `<span class="hidden">Calendar icon</span>`

Thanks

Comment: Are you using pseudo-elements for the icons? Isn’t that normally done like this: `<a href='#'><i class="icon-calendar"></i></a>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `aria-label` attribute to describe these links.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use the attribut `title=""` on the link ?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, links should not be empty, if your component needs to use an icon to visually represent something, it may not be interesting to use a `<a>` tag for this.

Links must be clickable and take the user somewhere. Using aria-label or title will not solve the problem.